# how to install a downloaded package in ubuntu

Tags: gcc

I have already downloaded gcc-3.0 from http://mirrors-usa.go-parts.com/gcc/releases/gcc-3.0/ and I extracted it. now I do not know how I can install it?

Comment: You do not need to install GCC. It is already installed.

Answer (score 1):

gcc is available in the repository.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gcc
```